# Can permanent critical damage be healed/prevented?

Tags: critical-hit, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars

I'm trying to understand how healing critical damage /critical injuries in SWEotE works.

The rulebook is clear for the easy stuff: if you get a scratch,  or are stunned e.g.,   the effect is (temporal) limited, but you *still need to explicitly heal* the critical injury to not suffer the cumulative +10 on subsequent ones.

What is not clear to me however is the difficult crit dmg (90+) where the effects are permanent (blind, lame, ability dmg) and it *doesn't* *explicitly* state that the effect is terminated by healing the crit:

Is the effect healed / prevented by healing the crit, or does the effect have to be healed separately if possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Permanent* and *Temporary* injuries are in the sense that their *effects* either last until the end of the current encounter, or their effects will last until the critical injury is healed.

Paraphrasing the core rulebook:

> The short-term effects of some injuries are **temporary**
>
> Other injuries are more serious and represent some sort of **long-term debilitation or impairment**. These injuries continue to affect the character until he receives the proper medical treatment to recover from the injury.

CRB pg 216-218

You can tell them apart when the description says: **Until healed**.

Effects that affect your character *until healed* will keep causing the effect until you (or a doctor) pass a *Medicine* check to remove the critical wound.

While **short-term effects** will end as soon as the encounter is over (mostly).
But the critical injury is not removed, meaning that if you suffer another critical injury, you must add **+10 per critical injury** on your character when rolling the d%.

I will give you four examples that covers all situations:

> **Bowled Over**: The target is knocked prone and suffers 1 strain

This effect is immediate, you suffer it's penalties and it's done, but you will have to heal the critical injury using Medicine later on, otherwise you will get +10 on all future critical injury checks (same goes for the next examples).

> **Agonizing Wound**: The target increases the difficulty of all Brawn and
> Agility checks by one until the end of the encounter.

This effect will (clearly) last until the end of the current encounter, but the critical injury will persist until healed with a Medicine check.

> **Crippled**: One of the target's limbs (selected by the GM) is crippled
> until healed or replaced Increase difficulty of all checks that
> require use of that limb by one.

This effect will last until you or someone else rolls a Medicine check to remove the critical injury. Passing a Medicine check will remove the critical injury and this effect.

> **Maimed**: One of the target's limbs (selected by the GM) is permanently
> lost. Unless the target has a cybernetic replacement, the target
> cannot perform actions that would require the use of that limb. All
> other actions gain ■

This effect will persist even after the critical injury is healed. Your only option is to obtain a cybernetic replacement to remove this effect. Passing a Medicine check will only heal the critical injury, but not the effect.

Comment: Does your answer complement or contradict the one of @aramis?

Comment: His answer isnt actually correct. Permanent imparments can be removed if the effect says *until healed*.

Comment: So you would say that if it *doesn't* state "until healed" (e.g. the ability damage entry), then it is *not* removed by healing the crit, right?

Comment: And if it states "until healed", you would say that the effect is removed by healing the crit? That's somewhat problematic with the forulation they choose wrt. the "crippled" entry, where it seems to imply the limb has to be healed/replaced separately. (I can't put quotes here, as I only have the german version of the rules)

Comment: When you become crippled, it says it will last *until healed*. Thats why you didnt *lose* the member, it just has a penalty. But the one following it (Maimed) says  you must replace the limb.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for adding in the quotes. Had a hard time translating that from german to en to get the details. I think one of the reasons I asked here is exactly **Crippled**: It not really clear to me whether the "until healed" thing here refers to healing the crit, or whether this would need a separate more complicated check: I think I will write up a separate question later as that needs more dissembling IMHO.

Comment: Follow up: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82832/how-do-you-heal-a-crippling-critical

Answer (score 0):

The healing of permanent impairment crits does not remove the impairment; it does remove the +10 on future crit rolls.