# How do you heal a crippling critical?

Tags: critical-hit, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars

Note: Follow up to: [Can permanent critical damage be healed/prevented?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82808/can-permanent-critical-damage-be-healed-prevented)

SWEotE has one specific entry in the Critical Injuries table:

> **Crippled**: One of the target's limbs (selected by the GM) is crippled
>   until healed or replaced Increase difficulty of all checks that
>   require use of that limb by one.

It is clear that to remove the stacking effect of the "meta" critical injury, one has to apply the appropriate healing check as listed in the table at least once.

It is unclear to me whether or how the crippling effect itself is healed by this or how these relate to one another:

- Do you have to apply an independent "generic" healing check to remove the critical and another "specific" healing check to heal the limb?
- Or is the healing check (from the table) actually a healing check to heal the limb, that is, you *have to heal the limb* in order to remove the critical injury from the crit stack?

The difference here to me is not so much whether I need one or two checks, but that the GM may rule that to actually heal the limb (the text quotes "healed *or replaced*") one has to have special medical equipment that is not available on the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the **Crippled** effect you have a few options:

- **Natural Rest** for a week and roll a **Resilience Check** to remove the *Critical Injury*. This will remove both the penalty and the critical injury.
- Recieve **Medical Care**, and after a week of treatment the doctor can roll a **Medicine Check**. This will remove both the penalty and the critical injury.
- Buy a **Cybernetic Replacement**. The cheapest one is 1000 credits. And how long it will take can go from a couple of hours to a couple of days, at most. This will remove the penalty immediatelly, but not the critical injury.

Comment: Cheers. Is the "week of treatment" for the **Medical Care** from the rule book? Is this specific for crits? Normal wounds don't need a week to heal, do they??

Comment: By normal wounds you mean damage taken during combats? No, those are healed naturally. You can recover one wound per full night of rest. Medical Care requires the medicine check and should only be required for critical injuries. You can also roll a medicine check after each encounter to recover wounds (1 wound per success, 1 strain per advantage).

Comment: This "week of treatment" means you cannot go around adventuring while recieveing medical care.